# Replacing values in a list by matching with dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the values in a list if a match is found with dictionary key. But i am getting the same list as output

**Code**

```
data = ['18. September 2021', '7. Juni 1946', 'Mai 2021, 19', '16.9.2021']

dictionary = {"Januar":"January","Februar":"February","März":"March","April":"April","Mai":"May","Juni":"June",
             "Juli":"July","August":"August","September":"September","Oktober":"October","November":"November",
             "Dezember":"December"}

for key in dictionary.keys():
    for index,i in enumerate(data):
        value = i.upper().replace(key, dictionary[key])
        data[index] = value

print(data)
```

**Expected Output**

```
['18. September 2021', '7. June 1946', 'May 2021, 19', '16.9.2021']
```

Comment: Since you attempt to `.replace` within `i.upper()` which is uppercase, of course the `key` isn't found - because your `dictionary` has titlecase keys.

Comment: @all Yeah thank you for pointing me that

Comment: remove .upper()

Comment: If you want to do case-insensitive matching with normalized case output, it would be better to lowercase all strings once before the main loop, do *all* the replacements using a lowercase->lowercase mapping, and finally fix the case to the normalized standard.

Comment: For reference for future questions: your output *isn't* "the same list", but instead uppercased. Realizing this would help find the problem, which is why it's useful to *show* the *exact* output, formatted as code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is the `upper()`: You convert the date to uppercase, but then try to replace the non-uppercase month names. Remove the `upper()` entirely, or make the dates uppercase *after* the replacements.

However, you could also combine the dictionary keys to a regular expression and use `re.sub` with a callback function to replace them all at once:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = "|".join(dictionary)
>>> p
'Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember'
>>> [re.sub(p, lambda m: dictionary[m.group()], d) for d in data]
['18. September 2021', '7. June 1946', 'May 2021, 19', '16.9.2021']
```